# Is a one-way magnetoelectric effect possible?

Tags: magnetic-fields, piezoelectric

If a piezomagnetic material is mechanically coupled to a piezoelectric material we observe the indirect magnetoelectric effect. A magnetic field $H$ leads to strain $\varepsilon$ and stress $\sigma$ resulting in an electric polarisation $P$:

$H \rightarrow \varepsilon \rightarrow \sigma \rightarrow P$

As far as I know, this effect usually also occurs in the opposite direction:

$P \rightarrow \sigma \rightarrow \varepsilon \rightarrow H$

Is it possible (e.g. by utilizing certain materials) to build a composite in which the effect only occurs in one direction (energy flow in only one direction similar to the current through an electrical diode)?